# Convergence of sum on lattice in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, integer-lattices, absolute-convergence

I am trying to understand why the following sum converges
$$\sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda\backslash\{0\}}\frac{1}{|\lambda|^3},$$
where $\Lambda=\{m+n\tau  \mid m,n\in \mathbb{Z} \}$ with $\tau \in \mathbb{C},\text{Im}(\tau)>0$. I understand why the sum 
$$\sum_{m,n\in \mathbb{Z}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}}\frac{1}{(m^2+n^2)^{3/2}}$$
converges (this is the case $\tau=i$), but I am having trouble generalizing this for arbitrary $\tau$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193669/convergence-of-the-eisenstein-series) and other references on Eisnestein series.